# PHP preg_match function: How can I write a true pattern for preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match, simple-html-dom

I tried to load a specific `div` of an external webpage into a specific `div` of my website  So I have used `preg_match` function to get part of the code.
but I think that I write wrong pattern.
this is my code:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = new simple_html_dom();


   $url = "http://something.com/";
   $page_all = file_get_contents($url); 
   preg_match('#<table id="table1"><table id="table1"><table id="table2">(.*)</table></table></table>#ms', $page_all, $div_array);

   echo ($div_array[0]);
?>
```

I want to get content of the second `table` with `id=table2` in http://somthing.com 
then it was'nt have any result.

Comment: [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476) Seriously.

Comment: @deceze do you expect that a xml parser reads a document with more than one html tag? By the way if you don't own this page and have not ask the owner of the page to use parts of it, this is criminal what you want to do.

Comment: You already require and instantiate simple_html_dom in your script. Why don't you use it to find the elements you're looking for?

Comment: @rekire http://mesghal.com is a site that publish Exchange rates and gold prices daily. I Want to extract gold prices from this site, and apply my own css to it.

Comment: @VolkerK please see my question. I have used `simple_html_dom.php` in my code `include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = new simple_html_dom();
`

Comment: ...and where do you use it? Apparently nowhere as there is only one occurence of `$html` in the code snippet and that's where you instantiate the simple_html_dom object.

Comment: @rekire Sorry, not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @VolkerK yes you're right, so please explain that how can I use `simple_html_dom` in this example?

Comment: Just take a look at a simple_html_dom tutorial, e.g. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/

Comment: @deceze the source code of that linked page is trash. XML parsing is impossible.

Comment: @Meghdad Hadidi I don't expect that the owner of that page wants that you use his data. That is why I won't help you directly. Look for some webservices to get the data legally.

Comment: @rekire this site is just an example at all. I want to use this way to extract data from sites that haven't `RSS` or site like: http://timaanddate.com that can not organize the `RSS` with my own `CSS`.

Answer (score 1):

Some characters in regular expressions have special meaning, so you have to escape them.
Special characters are:

```
. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | :
```

You can use preg_quote to escape them automatically

Comment: Please more explain of how to write a true pattern for extract `table2` in blow code:  <table id=table1><table id=table2></table</table>